# POST Web Service Client using C#

Tags: c#, web-services, webservice-client

Can you please give me a sample example of how to make the JSON request body in C#. I am using Visual Studio 2015. I know SOAP UI, but I am new to C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember in future that you need to give some code samples of what you tried, but see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

Lets assume you have the following webmethod

```
public void Webmethod(string parameter)
{
    //Do what ever
}
```

In C# you will do the following to call the webmethod, You require Json.net, Newtonsoft or other Json serializer

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http:\\www.somesite.com/path/to/webservice/webservice.asmx/Webmethod");
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Build a Json object representing the parameters

```
var jsonobjectrepresentingparameters = new {parameter = "Value"};
```

Get the Json string using Newtonsoft JsonConvert

```
var datastring = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonobjectrepresentingparameters);
```

Get the bytes

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(datastring);
```

Write the bytes to the request

```
var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0,bytes.Length);
```

Get repsonse

```
var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

If your Webmethod returned anything like a string, int or other data you can use the following class to deserialize

```
public class Type<T>
{
    public T D { get; set; }
    public Type()
    {

    }
}
```

You will notice when you work with webservices it returns a json object with property d as the value which is why you require the above class in C#
Then you will require the following extra two lines if your return type was string

```
var json = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
var object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type<string>>(json);
```